# Apply normal direction into a locator orientation, in OpenMaya?

Tags: maya

I have normal directions, is there some way to apply these values into a locator so this locator can point to the same direction of these normal values? It needs to be done in OpenMaya. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With MFnMesh you can retrieve the normals/positions of vertices/faces from a mesh, and use this data to construct the transformation matrix for each locator.

https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2019/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_1_1_m_fn_mesh_html

Comment: thanks claudio, but I have no knowledge enough to do this just checking the docs.. this is why I am asking here.. but thanks a lot for your reply!